# System.ArgumentException: error during decryption

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I am running SharePoint 2010 Configuration wizard to check for errors and I am getting following error in Log.

> System.ArgumentException : error during decryption. system error code
>   0. at microsoft.sharepoint.administration.SPCredentialManager.DecryptWithKey(Byte[]
>   rgbEncryptedPassphrase  GetFarmEncryptionKey DecryptWithMasterKey
>   GetSecureStringValue SPWebServiceInstance.Provision

Actually I was trying to deploy WSP via **Update-SPSolution**.

Getting this error:

> Error during decryption. system error code 0.

When I try to update WSP by **Update-SPSolution** or run any other SharePoint command.

[image]

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: are you runing this PSConfig under Farm Administrator Account? The One you set while installing SP16? - PSConfig under "Run As Administration" too?

Comment: yes, i am using farm admin account, running as Administrator.

Comment: i have created a test environment, and created new Config database. Now i can deploy WSP without any error, these issues not there. But how to resolve this issue on Production environment ? Creating new config database on Production is like full farm setup and need to recreate/reconfigure everything.